# How to prevent tinymce editor content from users modifying. user should not edit the content. How to do using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to prevent my data in tinymce editor. Should not allow to edit the content. How to do this in angularjs. Thanks in advance. For example. I want provide contenteditable false dynamically. How to provide this. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking:

```
<div ng-if="!contentIsEditable"><textarea></textarea></div>

<div ng-if="contentIsEditable"><mce-directive></mce-directive></div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.contentIsEditable=($scope.userType==="editor")?true:false;
```